# How can I unit test a wrapper around a condition_variable::wait?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, c++17

I have a class that has a `wait` function that waits for a queue to be filled up. Once the queue is non-empty, the `condition_variable` is notified, and the waiting function empties the queue and processes its elements.

I'd like to verify in a unit test that this `wrapper::wait` call (which checks if the queue is non-empty) actually blocks the thread. I have a flaky setup with an `atomic_bool` that is set after the wait call and thought naively that doing the following sequence would work.

1. Create thread with function that calls `wait`, then sets the `atomic_bool`.
2. After thread creation, verify `atomic_bool` has begin value
3. Push something into queue in the main thread, making the `atomic_bool` change value from the other thread.
4. Verify the changed value in the main thread.

There are two missing synchronization points: the two "verify"s aren't guaranteed to happen when I want them to:

- I can't verify that wait has been called in the thread.
- I can't verify the thread has had the chance to change the `atomic_bool`.

Is there any way to solve this problem without adding one or more additional `condition_variables`/`mutexes` to synchronize the operations?

Comment: Isn't the mutex that's already required for a condition variable enough to help you synchronize other actions (such as flagging wait as being called and changing your boolean).

Comment: @paddy if I break the wrapper's encapsulation of said mutex, maybe yes. That might be the best option.

Answer (score 1):

This would really be the perfect scenario for using [`std::condition_variable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable), but anyway: you can use several synchronization points with an `std::atomic<int> gate`. The various values will encode the different stages of the test. Waiting more than some constant time *T* for the value to change is to be considered test case failure<sup>1</sup>.

- `gate == 0`: secondary thread not initialized.
- `gate == 1`: secondary thread initialized, but it didn't respond yet.
- `gate == 2`: secondary thread initialized and running, can assume has called `wait`.
- `gate == 3`: main thread has added something to the queue, secondary thread is still likely to be waiting.
- `gate == 4`: secondary thread has exited `wait` and set the last value.

You may omit a couple of synchronization points if you like.

### Main thread

1. Set `gate` to 0.
2. Spawn secondary thread.
3. Set `gate` to 1.
4. Wait *T* for `gate` to become 2; on failure: *"secondary thread never reached `wait`"*.
5. Add something to the queue, set `gate` to 3.
6. Wait *T* for `gate` to become 4; on failure: *"secondary thread never exited `wait`"*.
7. Wait *T* for the secondary thread to join; on failure: *"secondary thread hung before exit"*.

### Secondary thread

1. Wait *T* for `gate` to become 1; on failure *"main thread hung after spawning"*.
2. Set `gate` to 2. Call `wait`.
3. (call to `wait` exits; queue has been processed).
4. Wait *T* for `gate` to become 3; on failure *"travelled back in time"*.
5. Set `gate` to 4 and exit.

To implement the "wait and check" part you can use [`compare_exchange`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/compare_exchange) and [`std::chrono`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono). A possible implementation may be like this:

```cpp
#include <atomic>
#include <chrono>
#include <condition_variable>

std::cv_status wait_till_reaches(
    std::atomic<int> &gate,
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::duration const &rel_time,
    const int desired_value,
    bool increment = false
) {
    const int next_value = desired_value + (increment ? 1 : 0);
    int dummy = desired_value;
    const std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    while (not gate.compare_exchange_weak(dummy, next_value)) {
        dummy = desired_value;
        if ((std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - start) >= rel_time) {
            return std::cv_status::timeout;
        }
    }
    return std::cv_status::no_timeout;
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> This is not testing *exactly* whether your code is working, rather if it's working *fast enough*, but on the other side if you have some threading issue it is not guaranteed that the test case will catch it either (at some point you have to decide how much time you wait for a response).

Answer (score 0):

One way to test this case is adding some trace or log lines with time before and after wait.  In the end you will compare the trace or trace file with some reference to see if the enevts happened as expected.

Comment: Time can vary and isn't absolute in the case of multiple threads, even in this simple case. I'd like a 100% rock solid solution...

Comment: Time do not have to be matxhed 100%, what important is the order and the duration between set signal and catch condition change.